# Birt Viewer Database Configuration

Tags: birt

I am getting problem to set database connection.
 Can you help me to set connection for web application of birt viewer.
how to set database connection to web or data source.

Comment: why can't you configure JNDI-Name in ur birt report ?

Comment: thanks for giving reply, right now its working some version issue I just changed in xml 3.7 to 2.2 than it working fine